# Looking for steps/theorems for this Boolean algebra conversion

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm usually pretty good at Boolean algebra, but I can't seem to figure out the theorems/steps involved in the following equation conversion:

C = AB + AD + BD

to

C = AB + D(A xor B)

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What do your operations mean? Does $+$ mean XOR and $\cdot$ mean $\wedge$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$AD + BD = D(A+B)\qquad\text{distribution}$$
$$D(A+B) = D(AB + \overline{A}B + A\overline{B})\qquad\text{showing all cases for OR}$$

$$AB + D(AB + \overline{A}B + A\overline{B}) = AB + DAB + D(\overline{A}B+A\overline{B})\qquad\text{distribution}$$

$$AB + DAB + D(\overline{A}B+A\overline{B}) = AB + D(\overline{A}B+A\overline{B})\qquad\text{absorption: }X+XY = X$$

$$AB + D(\overline{A}B+A\overline{B}) = AB + D(A\oplus B)\qquad\text{definition of xor}$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a useful equivalence:

**Reduction**

$$P + P'Q = P + Q$$

which can be generalized to:

**Generalized Reduction**

$$PR + P'QR = PR + QR$$

Applied to your statement:

$$AB + D(A \oplus B) \overset{Def. \ \oplus}{=}$$

$$AB + D(AB' + A'B) \overset{Distribution}{=}$$

$$AB + DAB' + DA'B \overset{Gen'd Reduction \times 2}{=}$$

$$AB + DA + DB$$